# Make global results package independent struts 2

Tags: struts2

When global results are configured outside a package in struts.xml dtd says I can't do that. How to have one error page as a result for unforeseen error result across packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is leverage package inheritance:

```
<package name="myapplication-default" extends="struts-default">
  <!- place your global result definitions here in this package -->
</package>

<package name="someotherpackage-default" extends="myapplication-default">
  <!-- reuses configuration from myapplication-default -->
</package>
```